# How to ask for permissions inside the adapter class of android viewpager?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-permissions

I am displaying quotes for my app using viewpager and when the user long presses the quote I want to save the quote card view in the device gallery.
So I want to ask the user to write permission whenever the user long presses the quote. But I am not able to implement the methods for permissions inside the adapter class. Is it possible to ask for permissions inside adapter class?

I have implemented the code for saving the card view in device storage and it is working fine. I have to manually go to the settings app and allow storage permission for the app.
I want to check for permission when the user tries to save the quote by long-pressing it. I don't want to ask for permission when the app loads.

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class myAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] quotes;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView textView;

    public myAdapter(Context context, String[] quotes) {

        this.context = context;
        this.quotes = quotes;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return quotes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container, false );
        container.addView(view);
        textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button=view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final CardView cardView=view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        textView.setText(quotes[position]);

        textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                //I WANT TO ASK FOR STORAGE PERMISSION HERE.

                Bitmap ss=Bitmap.createBitmap(cardView.getWidth(), cardView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas=new Canvas(ss);
                cardView.draw(canvas);
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        context.getContentResolver(),
                        ss,
                        "Image",
                        "Captured ScreenShot"
                );

                Toast.makeText(context, "QUOTE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((ViewGroup) object);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your adapter class

```
public class myAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
String[] quotes;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView textView;
Button button;

//interface
CallBack callBack;

public myAdapter(Context context, String[] quotes, CallBack callBack) {

    this.context = context;
    this.quotes = quotes;
    this.callBack = callBack;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return quotes.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
    container.addView(view);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    final CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    textView.setText(quotes[position]);

    textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            callBack.onLongClick(cardView);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((ViewGroup) object);
}

public interface CallBack {
    void onLongClick(CardView cardView);
}

}
```

you must create one interface and pass to adapter class for create event long click for callback to mainactivity and to main activity class check permission and is ok save image

your main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Cardview cardview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myAdapter myAdapter = new myAdapter(this, new String[]{"1", "2", "3"}, new myAdapter.CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(CardView cardView) {
            this.cardview = cardview;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{""}, 200);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 200) {

        Bitmap ss=Bitmap.createBitmap(cardView.getWidth(), cardView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(ss);
        cardView.draw(canvas);
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                ss,
                "Image",
                "Captured ScreenShot"
        );

        Toast.makeText(context, "QUOTE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        this.cardview = null;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: It worked. I had to replace "this.cardView" with "cardView" inside the overrided onLongClick() of myAdapter.callback() in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your longClickListener

```
 textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            checkAndRequestPermissions();

            Bitmap ss=Bitmap.createBitmap(cardView.getWidth(), cardView.getHeight(), 
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas=new Canvas(ss);
            cardView.draw(canvas);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    context.getContentResolver(),
                    ss,
                    "Image",
                    "Captured ScreenShot"
            );

            Toast.makeText(context, "QUOTE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Add this method in your adapter

```
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

    int Write = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(drawerActivity, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int Read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(drawerActivity, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (Write != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (Read != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(drawerActivity, 
listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 101);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: works for me, Just replace the word "drawerActivity" with passing context.